# What is the remedy of lossy-join decomposition?

Tags: database, database-normalization

I know what is lossless decomposition and lossy decomposition. In lossy decomposition we get some wrong informations. But what is the remedy? I think if we join on *primary key* it will be not lossy?

Am I right? If I am will it be lossless also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: to achieve a lossless decomposition you have to split on the **functional dependencies**.
It seems that you already know the (formal) [theory behind it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless-Join_Decomposition), so I'll try to give you a glimpse of why that is true.

Say you have a relation R

```
R(author_id, author_name, post_id, post_date, post_title)
```

with FDs

```
author_id -> { author_name }
post_id -> { post_date, post_title }
```

Now, a good decomposition would be

```
(author_id, author_name, post_id) (post_id, post_date, post_title)
```

because `post_id` determines `post_date` and `post_title`, thus becoming a key. Since `post_id` is a key in r2, every row in r2 is a different row and we can join safely. Note that the **primary key** on the original relation was `(author_id, post_id)`, which is more than we actually need.

On the other hand, a bad decomposition would be

```
(author_id, author_name, post_id, post_date) (post_date, post_title)
```

because there is no FD `post_date -> post_title`, thus `post_date` is not a key in r2, thus `post_date` could have duplicate values. It should be obvious from a intuitive perspective that joining on a potential duplicate value will get us a ton of phanotom rows.